# how to display a list of items in react from a db

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to display a list of item from a database, but only those with the Id of the account I'm logged in the application.

I tried to import a previous state with the account and use the id in the api to get only those items, then i use componentWillMount to render the page with the items i selected from the database. I get that i can't use static  getDerivedStateFromProps and componentWillMount ("Warning: Unsafe legacy lifecycles will not be called for components using new component APIs.

StoricoView uses getDerivedStateFromProps() but also contains the following legacy lifecycles:
  componentWillMount

The above lifecycles should be removed")

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import StoricoItems from "./Storicoitems";
import { styles } from "./styles.scss";
import { Form, Label, Input } from "components/Form";
import * as accountActionCreators from "core/actions/actions- account";
import * as contractActionCreators from "core/actions/actions-contract";
import * as assetActionCreators from "core/actions/actions-asset";
import { requestAccountAccess } from "core/libs/lib-metamask-helper";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class StoricoView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allowToProceed: false,
      email: "",
      receiverCode: "",
      initialDate: "",
      expireDate: "",
      rights: "",
      codiceReferto: null,
      nextBtnDisabled: true,
      id: "",
      storico: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { actions } = this.props;

    requestAccountAccess(defaultAccount => {
      actions.account.setDefaultAccount(defaultAccount);
      actions.contract.setContract(defaultAccount);
    });
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(prevState) {
    const { account } = prevState;
    return { id: account.id };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.mostraStorico(this.state.id);
  }

  mostraStorico(id) {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/assegna_consensos/" + id);
    then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      this.setState({ storico: response.data }, () => {
        console.log(this.state);
      });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  render() {
    const storicoItems = this.state.storico.map((storico, i) => {
      return <StoricoItems key={storico.public_key} item={storico} />;
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Storico</h1>
        <ul className="container">{storicoItems}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    account: state.account,
    asset: state.asset
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: {
      account: bindActionCreators(accountActionCreators, dispatch),
      contract: bindActionCreators(contractActionCreators, dispatch)
    }
  };
}

StoricoView.propTypes = {
  account: PropTypes.shape({
    email: PropTypes.string,
    receiverCode: PropTypes.string,
    initialDate: PropTypes.date,
    expireDate: PropTypes.date,
    rights: PropTypes.string,
    codiceReferto: PropTypes.string,
    id: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired,
  actions: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired,
  asset: PropTypes.shape({}),
  history: PropTypes.shape({}).isRequired
};

StoricoView.defaultProps = {
  asset: null
};

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )(StoricoView)
);
```

While StoricoItems is :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class StoricoItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      products: props.products
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <li className="registration-form">
        <ul className="container">
          <li className="registration-form">
            Proprietario : {this.state.products.giver}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="container">
          <li className="registration-form">
            Beneficiario : {this.state.products.receiver}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="container">
          <li className="registration-form">
            Data inizio consenso : {this.state.item.data_inizio}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="container">
          <li className="registration-form">
            Data Fine Consenso : {this.state.item.data_fine}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="container">
          <li className="registration-form">
            {" "}
            Tipo consenso : {this.state.item.diritti}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul className="container">
          <li className="registration-form">
            Referto :{this.state.item.referto}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <br />
        <br />
      </li>
    );
  }
}
export default StoricoItem;
```

Of course i'm doing it wrong but what?

Answer (score 2):

First thing you shouldn't call API from componentWillMount and instead move the call to componentDidMount ([it's better to wait for the component to be mounted before making api call](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/302#issuecomment-345445888)). 
Then you can remove componentWillMount and the message will disappear. Indeed componenentWillMount is depracated in React v16.* and will be removed in React v17.
To explain what happened, since you use componentWillMount and getDerivedStateFromProps which is a replacement for componentWillMount React will prefer use getDerivedStateFromProps and won't call willMount method that's why your api call were never made

Comment: Thanks! it works, but the function doesn't get the ID, it gets nothing.